# AVD manager in Intellij is disabled

Tags: android, intellij-idea, flutter, avd-manager

I am logging this issue and solution (below) as, for the second time, I find myself wasting hours on it.

Answer (score 29):

Solution: 
File -> Settings -> Enter 'Android' into search bar. Select 'Android SDK'.

[image]

Select 'edit'. Intellij now asks to download the SDK (~800MB). Intellij becomes unresponsive whilst software downloads and installs (it seems clicking cancel waits until software has downloaded, to cancel). Takes about 5 minutes.

Once done AVD manager now active.
[image]

Comment: Thanks, i got one more way, from where it already done to my settings. I'll put it in answer

Comment: See also this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54770056/5164462, if Android doesn't show up in Tools at all.

Answer (score 3):

File > Project Structure > Dependencies and set SDK. 
This will set your Android SDK in settings also

[image]

[image]