# IntelliJ - Android: How to enable AVD/Device Manager in IntelliJ?

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-emulator, avd-manager

## Problem

I use IntelliJ as main tool to code everything that can be related with the JVM, including Android apps.

When started a few months ago, didn't set any virtual device with any of the android tools and used Genymotion instead.

At date accomplished to get my first job as developer and used the virtual devices for the first time, so tried to make an installation in my machine, but have the option disable:

[image: Proof 1]

[image: Proof 2]

## What I tried

The app it's executed, have configured and Android and Java SDK's, have the global variables in my machine configured.

Everything works, just the option seem disable.

I tried other posts in StackOverflow ([like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53497851/avd-manager-in-intellij-is-disabled)) and followed a [tutorial in GeekforGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/guide-to-install-and-setup-intellij-idea-for-android-app-development/), but everything just show that the manager should be enable.

## Edit

About my IntelliJ installation, here are te specifications:

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2022.3.2 (Community Edition)
Build #IC-223.8617.56, built on January 26, 2023
Runtime version: 17.0.5+1-b653.25 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
Linux 5.15.0-60-generic
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 750M
Cores: 4
Non-Bundled Plugins:
    com.github.catppuccin.jetbrains (2.0.8)
    color.scheme.CyberpunkColorScheme (0.2)
    com.xinkun.theme.md (1.7.12)
    com.markskelton.one-dark-theme (5.7.3)
    com.elliotwaite.cyberpunk_theme (1.0.12)
    com.github.ushiosan23.darktheme (1.0.2)
    https://github.com/DUNNIK (1.7)
    color.scheme.CyberpunkUI (0.2)
    com.jetbrains.darkPurpleTheme (1.3)
    izhangzhihao.rainbow.brackets (2023.1.3)
    org.jetbrains.compose.desktop.ide (1.3.0)
    com.haulmont.jpab (2022.5.4-223)

Kotlin: 223-1.8.0-release-345-IJ8617.56
Current Desktop: ubuntu:GNOME
```

Comment: What's your current IDEA version? If it is 2022.2.x, try to update to 2022.3.x to see if it helps. Might be related to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-299045

Comment: No, alredy have a 2022.3, specificaly "IntelliJ IDEA 2022.3.2 (Community Edition)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution

Well, after almost a month, finally resolved this problem.

For anyone wondering, all you have to do is set a correct and updated location of your *Android SDK*, and set the *Android Facets* to enable the device manager:

1. Android SDK: Go to *Settings* > Search for *Android SDK* > Enter the tab and select *Edit* > Set the correct path to your *SDK* and select the desired options to download or update > Follow the steps and done.

[image: IntelliJ Settings Pane]

[image: SDK Setup]

2. Android Facets: Go to *File* > Select *Project Structure* > Go to *Facets* > Set the *Facets* for your project (**The Facets are customized for every project, search for documentation to see how to setup**)

[image: Project Structure]

[image: Project Facet]

### References

- [Similar Problem on YouTrack Issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-308876/IntelliJ-Android-device-manager-disabled)
- [Same Problem on another Stackoverflow Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53497851/avd-manager-in-intellij-is-disabled)